# trouble with list_display in django. Possibly ForeignKey issue?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django and I have not had any luck trying to troubleshoot this issue. What I want is a list of songs that will display the songName, artist and album, but what I am getting is the single column unicode display that is the default in Django admin. Below is my relevant source code. Thank you.

```
##models.py##
class Artist(models.Model):
     artistName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
     artistInfo = models.TextField()
     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.artistName

class Album(models.Model):
     albumName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
     artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
     date = models.DateTimeField('Release Date')
     albumInfo = models.TextField()
     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.albumName

class Song(models.Model):
     songName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
     artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
     album = models.ForeignKey('Album')
     def __unicode__(self)
          return self.songName


##admin.py##
from django.contrib import admin
from radio.models import Artist, Album, Song

class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('songName', 'artist', 'album')

admin.site.register(Song, SongAdmin)
admin.site.register(Artist)
admin.site.register(Album)
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, I can't immediately see any problems. Are you sure you are running the code you think you are? Make sure you have saved you files, deleted any `*.pyc` files and restart the dev server.

Comment: The server has been restarted a few times and everything is saved, and nothing has been deleted. Is there any place I should look in the supporting files for the problem I am getting?

Comment: I had a duplicate admin.py where the correct code was written. I moved that admin.py to the correct place and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is 100% correct, you should see 3 columns.
[image: screenshot showing 3 columns]

P.S.: You've missed out the ":" after `def __unicode__(self):` in your `Song` class